# Why I can't drop foreign key using foreign key name but instead it accepts something like works_with_ibfk_2 type name?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE client (
  client_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  client_name VARCHAR(40),
  branch_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY(branch_id) REFERENCES branch(branch_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);

CREATE TABLE works_with (
  emp_id INT,
  client_id INT,
  total_sales INT,
  PRIMARY KEY(emp_id, client_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(client_id) REFERENCES client(client_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY(emp_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
 );
```

```
drop table client;
```

> Cannot drop table 'client' referenced by a foreign key constraint
>   'works_with_ibfk_2' on table 'works_with'.

```
alter table works_with drop foreign key client_id;
```

I'm getting this

> Can't DROP 'client_id'; check that column/key exists

Comment: What part of the error do you know understand?

Comment: So how do I supply a foreign key name??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created FOREIGN KEY(client_id) REFERENCES client(client_id) ON DELETE CASCADE, you did not supply a foreign key name so mysql provided one for you ('works_with_ibfk_2') - you cannot drop client because it is referenced by this fk. AND you cannot alter because the named fk (client_id) does not exist. You would need to drop works_with_ibfk_2 before you can drop client.

Comment: So how do I supply a foreign key name??

Comment: Where? in the create statement like this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html in the alter table alter table works_with drop foreign key <name>;